# Automated email reports

Tags: email, vps, ssrs, report

I have a VPS with a high loaded website. Are there any automated solutions to send me an email or SMS if my site is not working correctly (for example, web server does not respond or DDoS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like pingdom. They will externally monitor services or even look for a specific string which is returned by a web server etc.

http://pingdom.com/

You get one free probe without SMS messaging. You just pay for SMS credits as and when you use them. If you get by with just e-mails or push notifications to their apps they it's completely free for one probe.

Setup is so easy and you won't need to worry about a second monitoring server, they even e-mail reports every month for review.

Hope this works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is [xymon](http://xymon.sourceforge.net/), which can do E-mail and SMS. It is free (open source).

It provides alerts and reports from a central xymon server. It can be customized for your unique requirements. It monitors and collects historical information related to connectivity, CPU utilization, memory, disk utilization, process statuses, and much more.
Monitoring a web server (http/https) is very easy to do. There can be many xymon clients (Linux/Unix as well as Windows).

In addition, the notification feature can be disabled for defined holidays, and multiple notification contacts can be defined - each receiving notifications only when defined time periods have elapsed, which helps escalate an issue or find another tech if the primary contact is not responding.

You get a bird's eye overview in a browser: [a photo from linuxlinks.com](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090710053519613/Xymon.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you like to host the monitoring on an seperated machine (for example you NAS at home), you should have a look at: http://www.nagios.org/

For SMS with nagios:

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Notifications/SMS/SMS-Notification-via-aspsms-2Ecom/details

http://aspsms.com/

If you only like to by a service:

Have look at:

http://www.monitor.us

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method:

Put a file called `STATUS` with content `GOOD` in your document root. So you can access that file using following URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/STATUS
```

Then from some where execute following script using `cron`:

```
STATUS=$(curl -s http://www.domain.com/STATUS)
if [[ $STATUS == "GOOD" ]]; then
  echo "Its working fine"
else
  echo "Not able to access www.domain.com" | mail -s "Status of www.domain.com" you@email.com
fi
```

Of course, you can use what ever name and content for this file.